# How to update rows when there is multiple rows in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I  have an attribute table and attribute values table like:

```
id | Attribute Name
 2    Color
```

Now i'm saving this attribute values in another table attribute_values

```
id | attribute_id | values

1       2           Green
2       2           Red
```

Now there is a issue when i want to update its values, suppose on the update screen user may select only one attribute so i want to know which is the best way to update its values so that if any value is not present it can be removed on update. Right now i'm deleting the old rows and inserting new one but this will consume time.

Comment: Why Larevel version 4 and 5 tags? Are you using any models for the tables to update? Are there any relations?

Comment: @dbf: I'm using modals, but right now i' deleting the attribute values and adding it again on update of a particular attribute id, but i want to know is there any other better way to do this

Comment: I need to see the models and the relations they have with each other.